# using tar to collect files from several source-directories to one plain archive

Tags: linux, posix, archive, tar

I'm searching for hours now to get tar skipping all directory structure.

The closest approach to get what I want is the following:

`tar cf foo.tar -C /data/2012/12/12/00 . -C /data/2012/12/12/01 . -C /data/2012/12/12/03 .`

The Problem:
All files in the archive are located in the "." -folder. But they are expected in the root of archive.

Anyone out there with a hint for me?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the --transform option:

```
--transform 's,^\./,,'
```

I tried this on BSD with its similar -s option and it worked for me.